# Magento 1.9.2.4 cURL issue

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect, magento-connect-manager, curl

I am using Magento 1.9.2.4 and my Magento Connect is not working. Whenever I click check for updates, everything from the bottom disappears, please check the image below:

[image: Magento Connect Issue]

When I try to update Magento via SSH I get the following error:

> ./mage mage-setup 
>   Running initial setup... 
>   Success 
>   Success 
>   PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in /xxxxxxxx/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php on line 446

When I open the file, this is the code on that line:

> public function isAuthorizationRequired()
>       {
>           if (isset($_SESSION['auth']['username']) && isset($_SESSION['auth']['password'])
>               && !empty($_SESSION['auth']['username']))
>           {
>               return true;
>           }
>           return false;
>       }

I tried commenting out the line but then it gives an error for the next function and so on. I have already tried the unknown cipher in list fix as well but no success. Please guide me about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the issue. My curl.php file was corrupted as a result Magento Downloader was not working. So I replaced the file with Magento 1.9.2.4 git hub repo and now it works fine.

I did face an issue while updating to 1.9.4.0, it did not update via Magento Downloader, it gave the php version error so had to update it via ssh using --force command. I hope it helps.